# When creating a subscription in CloudKit I'm trying to create a predicate for a NSArray of Doubles and I keep getting errors

Tags: arrays, swift, nspredicate

The "PercentDone" NSArray of Doubles that looks like this when all index's are filled:

```
(0,0,0)
```

Here is the predicate:

```
predicate = NSPredicate(format: "PercentDone CONTAINS %@ && recordID == %@",Double(0), self.recordName!)
```

Here is the error I keep getting when viewing the subscription:

> server message = "Missing filter value";

Even when I search on Apple documentation I don't find much help using predicates with numbers or arrays. I've tried turning it into a string and filtering but still no answer I even trying making regular array filled with numbers but I still can't seem to use the predicate correctly. Even when try to use some of the predicate key words in the Apple archive documentation it doesn't work. Does anyone know how to create a predicate with a NSArray of numbers?

Comment: At least the specifier for a Double is `%f` rather than `%@`.

Comment: Thanks ill try that